# Is there a way to check if access-token issued by registry server has push access on the repository without attempting to push an image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to add a sanity check on my REST client that needs to check if supplied registry credential has `push` access on the repository. This is to set my client to ready state so it accepts image push requests to a private repository.

P.S.: I explored authorization flow to utilize `www-authenticate` response header to retrieve an access_token with push scope. However, it does not fail if supplied credential does not have push privilege on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the token, I don't believe there's a way unless you're the registry server configuring authorization. I treat the tokens as opaque, and different registries implement them different ways, plus some registries don't use token auth.

Rather than pushing an image, you could push a small dummy blob. If you can upload a 2 byte blob, you have push access. What you don't know is if the registry will accept image push, because there is more than just images that can be pushed, and registries have different levels of content validation. Some reject artifacts like Helm charts, some reject the old Docker schema v1 manifests, and some look at manifest size and how many annotations there.